# Breakpoints in Shared Libraries from breakpoint file

Tags: gdb

I set breakpoints in code in shared libraries and this works well.  I have to confirm `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?`. However when I want to save the breakpoints in a file for later use using

```
save breakpoints filename.bp
```

I find that I can't use them later with

```
source filename.bp
```

the breakpoints don't get set because of this:

```
   Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?
 (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

Which automatically answers no and doesn't set the breakpoint.  Is there a way to stop gdb asking for confirmation and have it create the breakpoints from the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is a reported [gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18183).

You can work around this by putting `set breakpoint pending on` in your `.gdbinit`.  That's what I did.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll give that a try